# How to link multiple window's focuses in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

*python 3.8.2*

Goal: link multiple windows (root and topLevels) together so if one of them is clicked (has focus) all of the topLevels and root come up in front of the unrelated windows on the desktop in other words all of them have focus but not really

I kinda accomplished this but with only the root because if I included the other 2 toplevels to do the same it would be stuck in a loop.
Even so now the program cannot focus on the main root and every time root has focus it is passed on to one of the toplevels.

For this I wrote 2 functions and bound the focusIn and focusOut to these functions
Functions:

```
def Focus(event):
    global rootNoFocus
    global rpwNoFocus
    global cswNoFocus
    print(rootNoFocus, rpwNoFocus, cswNoFocus)
    if rootNoFocus == True and rootNoFocus == True and rootNoFocus == True:
        rndPassWin.focus()
        clickerSetupWin.focus()
    
    if event.widget == root:
        rootNoFocus = False
    if event.widget == rndPassWin:
        rpwNoFocus = False
    if event.widget == clickerSetupWin:
        cswNoFocus = False
        
               
def noFocus(event):
    global rootNoFocus
    global rpwNoFocus
    global cswNoFocus
    
    if event.widget == root:
        rootNoFocus = True
    if event.widget == rndPassWin:
        rpwNoFocus = True
    if event.widget == clickerSetupWin:
        cswNoFocus = True
```

Binding:

```
root.bind('<FocusIn>', Focus)
root.bind('<FocusOut>', noFocus)
rndPassWin.bind('<FocusOut>', noFocus)
clickerSetupWin.bind('<FocusOut>', noFocus)
```

Comment: In tkinter having "focus" simply determines the widget that keyboard input will be sent to, nothing more. I think you want to `lift()` or `lower()` the display order of windows.

Comment: @martineau thank you I wasn't aware of such function's existence, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad to hear my slightly garbled comment helped. No apologies necessary, I think tkinter is very poorly documented (as well as operates in many "unpythonic" ways).

Comment: You can simply make all the `Toplevel` transient windows of the root window.